# Search and Replace a character inside uppercase strings

Tags: regex

I have a huge text file that contains a lot of typos of a mix of lowercase with uppercase characters but only with the letter "l" (lowercase L) and only within uppercase words, in this form:

```
VERONlCA, SPEAKlNG, lMITATlON, ENGLlSH
```

So I want to replace all characters 'l' (lowercase L) within an uppercase word only (as there are lot of lowercase words containing lowercase 'L' as well in a normal way) where the previous character is uppercase and the contiguous character is uppercase as well. Something like [A-Z] [l] [A-Z] and replace the lowercase 'L' with an uppercase 'I' (as in MIKE) but keeping the rest of the uppercase word intact and  without affecting the lower case strings throughout the rest of the document (so 'imagination' won't become 'ImagInation').

I'm using a Find and replace box, so what should I type in the find box and what should I type in the replace box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `([A-Z]|\b)l([A-Z])` with `\1L\2`. The slashes reference the groups.

It could also be `$1L$2` depending on the program.

Comment: Thanks or your prompt response, however your expression is also selecting lowercase strings such Clev**ela**nd, as if it is not enforcing the uppercase condition. Also, what about where the lower case L starts a word like **lM**AGINATION? I guess, it should be looking for [anything uppercase] and (lowercase L) or (lowercase L) and [anything uppercase]

Comment: @mistervela What text editor are you using? You might need to tick case-sensitive.

Comment: Sure, thanks. That I figured out. I posted the answer, maybe you will know how to combine the two expressions.

Comment: @mistervela You can use `\b` to match word boundaries, see if the updated version works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that whatever software you use to search and replace has to have the 'Match Case' checked.

First, I ended up using two regex commands:

Find

```
([A-Z])l([A-Z]+)
```

replace with

```
$1I$2
```

With this one you ensure the change is executed only on uppercase words, the lowercase words will be totally spared as [A-Z]+ will ensure that the contiguous characters next to the lowercase L are in uppercase, without it, it will match also lowercase words.

and

```
(l)([A-Z]+)
```

replace with

```
I$2
```

to make sure it will match words beginning with the lowercase L.

I'm sure there's a way I can combine these two commands in one, but I would not know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with leading and trailing `l`, you can do:

Find: `\b(?:([A-Z]+)l([A-Z]+)|l([A-Z]+)|[A-Z]+l)\b`
Replace: `\U$0`

Comment: Great, thanks. However your expression doesn't enforce that the search be made only within uppercase words, so I added this the part [A-Z]+ like this: (?<=[A-Z])l([A-Z]+)|([A-Z]+)l(?=[A-Z]) and now it works.

Comment: @mistervela: It matches `l` only when preceeded OR followed by an uppercase or both, ie. `ABCl` or `lDEF` or `ABClDEF`, isn't what you want?

Comment: Yeah, but your expression doesn't make the search within uppercase words only, it takes all words uppercase and lowercase where the lowercase L is present: abclef and ABClEF. That's why by adding the [A-Z]+ you make sure that the rest of the word have only uppercase letters. Your answer is great because it combines the two commands I was trying to execute (for a beginning and a trailing lowercase L )

Comment: @mistervela: No, it matches only what I write in previous comment. It doesn't match lowercase only word. May be your regex flavour doesn't support lookaround.

Comment: What text editor are you using? maybe mine is obsolete. In my text editor, your expression matches all the lowercase L in all words, uppercase and lowercase, even if I tick the 'Match Case' checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I doubled check your expression with SublimeText 3 and it's grabbing lowercase words too that start with an uppercase and then the lower case L, like Albert, Ellen, etc. The expression (?<=[A-Z])l([A-Z]+)|([A-Z]+)l(?=[A-Z]) (based on yours) makes sure it only searches within uppercase words.

Comment: @mistervela: OK, I see, my fault. But see my edit, it works fine now, at least with Notepad++